# Java: Returning ArrayList that is removed from any elements in 'phrases' that contain 'target.'

Tags: java

I want to remove any element that includes *target* string. *Target* can be the full element/word or a letter in the word, so I am having trouble with going through each letter in every element in the ArrayList. The code in the comments is a previous approach I took.

here is the original question:
 [image: here is the original question]

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeIt(ArrayList<String> phrases, String target) {
    /**
    for (int i = phrases.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int p = 0; p < phrases.get(i).length(); p++) {
            if (phrases.get(p) == target) {
                phrases.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    */
    for (int i = phrases.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int p = 0; p < phrases.get(i).length(); p++) {
            int index = phrases.indexOf(target);
            if (index == -1) {
                return phrases;
            } else { 
                phrases.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return phrases;
}
```

Comment: Have you run your code with the example inputs? What does it do wrong? Why do you think it does that incorrectly? What have you tried to make this work?

Comment: Read this - https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception, see if it helps in modifying your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting down is a good idea, and `indexOf()` can do the job. What you simply do not need is the inner loop and especially the `return` inside the inner loop, because that just gives up the work at the first mismatch.

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeIt(ArrayList<String> phrases, String target) {
    for (int i = phrases.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (phrases.get(p).indexOf(target) != -1) {
            phrases.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return phrases;
}
```

The condition for removal could use `contains()`, as there is no real need for the actual position of the match, knowing its presence is enough:

```
if (phrases.get(i).contains(target)) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do and will not give ConcurrentModificationException as well

```
Iterator<String> iterator = phrases.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   if(iterator.next().contains(target)) {
      iterator.remove();
   }
}
```